# When can I free range ducklings (NZ)

Tags: birds

I live on a lifestyle block which has lots if birds - including  ducks and pukekos who enjoy my pond.

One of my Pekin ducks recently hatched some ducklings - From 7 we are now down to 4. As a result of nature caused attrition we have kicked our chickens out there roost and given it to the mother and her ducklings.

How long before I can release them - that is to say allow them to join the rest of their flock grazing on my property ? (Or how big do the ducklings need to be to fend for themselves?

I am in rural Auckland, NZ, and there is a stream behind my property (no doubt harboring rats - and there are Pukekos as well). No Coyotes or dogs though!

For the sake of clarity, I'm not planning on releasing these ducklings into the wild - I just want to release them from the chicken coop.